# Is there any way to run more than one parallel job simultaneously using a single job script?

Tags: slurm, job-scheduling

Is there any way to run more than one parallel job simultaneously using a single job script? I have written a script like this. However, it is not processing four jobs simultaneously. Only 12 cores out of 48 are running a single job. Only one by one the four codes (from four different directories) are running.

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=my_job_name                     # Job name
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=48
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00                                   # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH -o cpu_srun_new.out
#SBATCH --partition=medium

module load compiler/intel/2019.5.281
cd a1
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output.txt
cd ../a2
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output.txt
cd ../a3
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output.txt
cd ../a4
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Commands in `sh` (like in any other shell) are blocking, meaning that once you run them, the shell waits for its completion before looking at the next comment, unless you [append an ampersand `&` at the end of the command](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/).

Your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=my_job_name                     # Job name
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=48
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00                                   # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH -o cpu_srun_new.out
#SBATCH --partition=medium

module load compiler/intel/2019.5.281
cd a1
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output1.txt &
cd ../a2
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output2.txt &
cd ../a3
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output3.txt &
cd ../a4
mpirun -np 12 ./a.out > output4.txt &

wait
```

Note the `&` at the end of the `mpirun` lines, and the addition of the `wait` command at the end of the script. That command is necessary to make sure the script does not end before the `mpirun` commands are completed.

Comment: This is not working for me. Again, it is not processing four jobs simultaneously. Only 12 cores out of 48 are running a single job in 1 directory out of 4. codes in the rest of the directories are not executing, and I left with 48-(12*3) unused processors.
Is there any way to divide the 48 processors into 4 parts before entering the directories?

Comment: I just noticed you redirect with truncation all output to the same file so in effect, you only have the output of the last `mpirun` in `output.txt`. Are you sure the other 36 processors are idle? Maybe they are working by your do not see it because their output is lost? Maybe try naming the output files differently.

Comment: This ```a.out``` creates many output files. Only time steps are written in output.txt. I am only getting those files in one directory. In other three directories I am only getting output.txt and other files are not generating in those three directories. And this output.txt in the other three directories are remaining blank.
And surprisingly, I am getting output files in a3, not in a4